# how to edit the data from "ngModel" before display in two way binding

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

```html
    <textarea #hello class="form-control" name="Input" type="text" rows="10" cols="40" [(ngModel)]="answer">
    </textarea>
    
    <div class="message">
      {{ answer }}
    </div>
```

```js
    transform(value: string): string {
        return value.replace(/\\n/g, '<br />');
      }
    answer = '';
```

My requirement is i need to get some data from user, store it in a variable, make some changes/replace a few things, preserve it's state (linebreaks, space) and then display it.

Can I intercept the data from ngModel before it is displayed and store it in a variable, make changes and then display it as normal ngModel

If this is not possible, appreciate any help in filling this requirement through any other method. Need some guidance

Comment: Create two variables, make the second variable recive your formated data. Anothe_var = value.replace(/\\n/g, '<br />');.      {{Another_var}}

Comment: hi, im stuck at, how to transfer data enter in ngModel form to variable, any example or reference will really help me. Basically, how to transfer data from html to ts :(

Comment: Your own example is already doing ir, once you use two way binding.[(ngModel)]="answer".  As longe as you type, you are transfering data to "answer" variable.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax

Comment: Yes, but you can't do any operations on it & it's real time. If i copy "answer" to "another-var", it won't work. 
If my message it "hello how are you", i need to edit it to "hi, how are you" & then display it, can i do it? I am sry if i sound stupid, is it possible to provide some small code of the same

Comment: Yes, It is possible. Just depend on which moment you wanna do It. As soon as the user type or when the user leave the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<textarea #hello class="form-control" name="Input" type="text" 
 rows="10" cols="40" [(ngModel)]="answer" (keyup) 
  ="onKeyUp($event)">
  </textarea>

  <div class="message">
 {{ formated }}
  </div>
```

typescript

```
onKeyUp(event: any)
{
This.formated = event.target.value.replace(/\\n/g, '<br />');
 }
 answer = '';
 formated: string
```

Comment: Woah! thanks it's working. One follow up question, sry to eat more of your time.
Can i do multiple editings as follows

`code`
onKeyUp(event: any) {
    this.formated = event.target.value.replace(/\\n/g, '<br />');
    this.formated = event.target.value.replace("hello","hi")
    this.formated = event.target.value.replace("what","wassup?")
    this.formated = event.target.value.replace("1","2")
  }

`code`

Comment: Yes, but something like this.  This.formated =
=  event.target.value.replace(/\\n/g, '<br />'); this.formated = this formated.replace("hello","hi") this.formated = this.formated.replace("what","wassup?") . I have no way to test now, but i guess this would do the job.